# How to align my submit and cancel buttons(in tr) to the bottom of the table

Tags: c#, html

How to align my submit and cancel buttons(in tr) to the bottom of the table?

Please help me out! Thanks guys!

.
.
.
.

```
        <tr align ="center" valign="bottom">
            <td align="center" valign="bottom">
               <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDisable" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/green-deactivate.gif" OnClick="btnDisable_Click"
                    ValidationGroup="group1" />

               <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.gif" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: That depends on how you want to align them. Same center line? Same bottom line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the td element add

```
style="vertical-align: bottom;"
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Why should this do something different than `valign="bottom"`?

Comment: I don't think it should, but CSS can be moved into a CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr valign="bottom">
```

see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_tr_valign.asp)

What way are they aligning for you? perhaps you should have the different buttons each within there own cell?

```
<tr>
   <td> ok </td> 
   <td> cancel </td>
</tr>
```